# system error {1003} in blackberry - eclipse

Tags: eclipse, blackberry-eclipse-plugin

> I had used **blacberry-eclipse** to create my first app which display html page from folder **"assests "** . but when i test on simulator I had error "**file:///Azan/index.html 
>
>  system error {1003}"  .**

```
        BrowserFieldConfig config = new BrowserFieldConfig();
        config.setProperty(BrowserFieldConfig.NAVIGATION_MODE,
        BrowserFieldConfig.NAVIGATION_MODE_CARET);      
        BrowserField test = new BrowserField(config);
        test.requestContent("file:///Azan/index.html");
```

Comment: what is the full path of a file/folder you're trying to access?
Is file:///Azan/index.html the one you're getting error on?

Comment: And is the file in SD card or not?

Comment: I put Azan folder in project directory as src , res ... . only created new folder and put html files on it .